# Problem with \tagged within \cventry. Produces error (in some arguments only)

Tags: errors, moderncv

I intend to use the `tagging`-package to organise my CV depending on, for example, which language I need it in. The problem with `\tagged{}` within `\cventry` is that it works fine on 2nd and 6th arguments, but not in 3rd, 4th, 5th... weird.

In the attached MWE, the first `cventry{2016}` works fine, but the second `{2015}` doesn't. Can anybody devise the problem? thank you!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{tagging}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{MWE}
%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\usetag{EN} %Three possible tags: EN, DE, SP

\section{Education}

\cventry{2016}
{\tagged{EN}{Mathematics}\tagged{DE}{Mathematik}\tagged{SP}{Matem\'aticas}}
{University}
{USA}
{(unfinished)}
{\tagged{EN}{Research}\tagged{DE}{Forschung} \tagged{SP}{Investigaci\'on}}

\cventry{2015}
{Pilot}
{\tagged{EN}{Academy}\tagged{DE}{Pilotschule} \tagged{SP}{Academia}} %uncommenting THIS LINE causes error
{}
{}
{}
{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default definition of `\cventry` uses `\ifthenelse` which can't handle your input:

*default definition*

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Use `\ifx` instead and it works:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifx&#4&\else{, {\slshape#4}}\fi%
    \ifx&#5&\else{, #5}\fi%
    \ifx&#6&\else{, #6}\fi%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{tagging} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifx&#4&\else{, {\slshape#4}}\fi%
    \ifx&#5&\else{, #5}\fi%
    \ifx&#6&\else{, #6}\fi%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{MWE}


%-----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\usetag{EN} %Three possible tags: EN, DE, SP

\section{Education}

\cventry{2016}
{\tagged{EN}{Mathematics}\tagged{DE}{Mathematik}\tagged{SP}{Matem\'aticas}}
{University}
{USA}
{(unfinished)}
{\tagged{EN}{Research}\tagged{DE}{Forschung} \tagged{SP}{Investigaci\'on}}

\cventry{2015}
{Pilot}
{\tagged{EN}{Academy}\tagged{DE}{Pilotschule} \tagged{SP}{Academia}} %uncommenting THIS LINE causes error
{}
{}
{}
{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! It works like a charm ;)